# Is this singleton implementation correct?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, java-8, singleton

As the double lock checking doesn't work on optimized compilers I am removing it from my singleton class and instead of going for early initialization.

Below is my new singleton class :

```
class MySingleton {
    private static volatile MySingleton myInstance = new MySingleton();
    public static getInstance() {
        return myInstance;
    }
}
```

Apart from getInstance(), there are setter methods in the class which set the values of the member fields.

Hope this implementation will not cause any data inconsistency when multiple threads will be updating various member fields using the same object.

Any suggestions or inputs are welcome.

Comment: @HadiJ I completely agree i need to define a private constructor. But i suppose this would be thread safe and there is no need for synchronization as the static field would be created during class load. Since my reference is static it will always be available to any thread that tries to access.

Answer (score 3):

This code is thread-safe.  Indeed, you can remove the `volatile` and it will still be thread-safe.

The `myInstance` variable is initialized when static initialization is triggered (if it hasn't already happened) by the first `getInstance` call.  There is a *happens-before* from the initialization and the first call.

However, you also said this:

> Hope this implementation will not cause any data inconsistency when multiple threads will be updating various member fields using the same object.

You haven't shown any of the code for doing that, so we can't tell you whether *that* code is thread-safe.  If `MySingleton` instances are mutable, then the state-related methods must synchronize appropriately to prevents memory hazards and race conditions.  The code that you have shown us does not address this.

---

Since the default `MySingleton` constructor is `public`, this is not a proper singleton class.  Multiple instances can be created.

---

This implementation differs from many other implementations in that the distinguished `MySingleton` instance is created eagerly rather than lazily.  This simplifies the problem considerably.

Note that lazy initialization of singletons is often unnecessary.  If you don't specifically need lazy initialization, then the simpler eager alternative is just fine.

Comment: As you said, the instance is created on the first `getInstance` call, which is all but "created eagerly". The "many implementations" doing it differently usually try to solve a nonexistent problem.There's a mismatch between the appearances in media and the actual relevance of the singleton pattern in real life anyway.

Comment: And it must be emphasized that the implementation of the singleton has no impact on the safety of the updates made by the setter methods the OP mentioned in the question.

Comment: Incorporated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton is thread-safe, but there are things other than a call to `getInstance()` which could cause the `MySingleton` class to be initialized, which would construct the instance.

The usual way around this is to put the singleton in a private nested class like this:

```
class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton() {
        // there can only be one
    }
    private static class Holder {
        static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }
}
```

Now the instance can only be constructed when the `Holder` class is initialized, and that only happens in the first call to `getInstance()`